# SQLite C interface doesn't create sqlite_master table

Tags: c++, sqlite

It seems that SQLite C interface create database that doesn't contain `sqlite_master` table described in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7):

> From within a C/C++ program (or a script using Tcl/Ruby/Perl/Python
>   bindings) you can get access to table and index names by doing a
>   SELECT on a special table named "SQLITE_MASTER". Every SQLite database
>   has an SQLITE_MASTER table that defines the schema for the database

The following code creates a database that doesn't contain such table (`.tables` command returns nothing):

```
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main()
{
  sqlite3* db;
  sqlite3_open("helper.db", &db);
  sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Why? What should I do to create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.tables` command does not show any of the internal tables, but they do exist:

```
sqlite> create table t(x);
sqlite> .tables
t
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master;
table|t|t|2|CREATE TABLE t(x)
```

Comment: `select * from sqlite_master;` doesn't return anything in my case

Comment: Because you do not have any other tables. But without the master table, the query would have resulted in an error message.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Where can I see the `sqlite_master` table then?

Comment: What do you mean with "see"? It's shown in my example.

Comment: I mean, is there any command (like `.tables` or `.schema`) in the command line utility that will show the `sqlite_master` table?

Comment: No. And [its structure](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master) is always the same, so why bother?